# IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005) on SQL Query

Tags: vb.net

This is my Query

```
SELECT TOP 1 MAX(CAST(Id AS int)) , Ddate, Name FROM WonPrize WHERE Ddate=@Ddate GROUP BY Id,Ddate,Name
```

The Query is giving me an error code on VB.NET.

```
IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)
```

I don't think I have an error with the syntax that I am composing

I am trying to display the MAX ID but MAX(Id) is not displaying the Number 2 Id so I tried to use this MAX(CAST(Id AS int)). and it gives me an error code.
What should be my mistakes?

I am using the oledb.

Comment: Exclude `Id` from `GROUP BY` clause - this field is included into output fieldset as an argument of aggregate function. PS. Where do you substitute the @Ddate placeholder with the value and how do you do it? PPS. You select data for a single date only, and it is known (@Ddate). I'd recommend to exclude this field from SELECT and GROUP BY sections.

Comment: @Akina I already excluded that Id from the group but nothing happen. anyway, I have resolved the problem on my own. Thank You for the response.

Comment: @Biswapriyo there is no Access issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to oledb bug on VB.NET I just change the syntax.

From:

```
SELECT TOP 1 MAX(CAST(Id AS int)) , Ddate, Name FROM WonPrize WHERE Ddate=@Ddate GROUP BY Id,Ddate,Name
```

To:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Id, Ddate, Name FROM WonPrize WHERE Ddate=@Ddate AND Id=(SELECT MAX(Id) FROM WonPrize)
```

And This resolves my Problem.

oledb is not working together with 2nd and 3rd column value using MAX(value) and MIN(value) I decided to put it on WHERE statement since the MAX and MIN will only work on oledb on a single value. And I think that the First syntax is only working on SQLClient and not on OLEDB.